# Java: How do I get user's email with box api v2

Tags: java, box-api, email-client, box, boxapiv2

I building a java desktop app, It can download and upload files with box.com
I've added a few libraries in https://github.com/box/box-java-sdk-v2/tree/master/BoxJavaLibraryV2/libs

It worked, but I need i get user's email to manage account.
I can't find example in

```
github.com/box/box-java-sdk-v2
```

To get it.

Thank for your reading, i'm so sorry for my bad english.

Comment: This is my new code, I hope you can save time with it:

boxclient = new BoxClient(BOX_CLIENT_ID, BOX_CLIENT_SECRET, hub, parser, boxconfig); 
BoxOAuthToken token; 
try { 
token = boxclient.getOAuthManager().refreshOAuth(box_com_token, BOX_CLIENT_ID, BOX_CLIENT_SECRET);
box_com_token = token.getRefreshToken();
boxclient.authenticate(token); 

BoxUser user = boxclient.getUsersManager().getUser("me", null);

}catch (BoxRestException | BoxServerException 
| AuthFatalFailureException e) { 
// TODO Auto-generated catch block 
e.printStackTrace(); 
}

Comment: Or you can see here: https://support.box.com/hc/en-us/requests/730898

Answer (score 1):

You can query a user's email using the [Get's User Info API](https://box-content.readme.io/reference#users). The user's email will be returned in the JSON response as the value for the key "login".